# Boolean value in CSS3 style attribute

Tags: javascript, css, attributes, boolean

In CSS3, is there any attribute that takes `false` or `null` value? I suppose and expect not, but wanted to make sure.

I am writing a javascript code (related to ajax interaction) that sets or removes an attribute to/from some DOM object. The function takes an attribute name and its value as the arguments, and I am thinking that, if the value turns out to be `false` or `null`, then `removeAttribute()` function should be called, and otherwise, the attribute should be assigned with that value. If there is a style attribute that possibly takes `false` or `null` value, then I cannot do that, so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: All valid css values are strings.

Comment: @kennebec Aren't integers also possible? -- That's what I had thought, but I assume you are right. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no attribute that takes `false` or `null`.  However, I am pretty sure you can create your property without any visual impact.

Comment: The attribute I am bothered with is, for example, `loop` attribute used in `<audio>`. This kind of attributes are supposed to be absent when you want it to be "false", so if I set it to something like `loop=false`, it is still recognized as `true` as long as the attribute is there. That is why I need to remove it instead of assigning `false`.

Comment: Actually, I tested it now, and if I set a value as `false`, it does indeed seem to be recognized as `false`. I will be asking another question to make sure about this point.

Comment: @sawa `loop=false` remains true unless the entire `loop` attribute is removed.  Basically, the presence of just `loop` is what a tag needs to do something else.  You need to use something like jQuery to remove the entier `loop` attribute (or at least that's what I would do).  Now, if you set a different undefined attribute to false, then you are able to recognize it as false.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I just posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775782 about the same time you commented back. I am with javascript, and I did `loop=false`, and that seems to have effect in stopping the loop of the audio play back. Maybe what you say is right, and this might be just a peculiar thing about Google Chorome. I will also see what others will say. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Even ones like [`speak-header`](http://www.css3.com/css-speak-header/) which have only two possible values can still accept the special value `inherit`.