# Setting false value vs. removing an attribute

Tags: html, boolean

I was reading something about boolean attribute [here](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-audio.php), which says that for a boolean attribute (in this particular example, `loop` attribute of `<audio>`), whatever value you set, it is going to be recognized as "true". In order to really set to falsy, you cannot set it like `loop=false` or with javascript as `['loop']=false`, but have to remove the attribute such as by doing `removeAttribute('loop')`. Is this true?

I first believed it, but as far as checked it with Chrome, it seems that setting to `['loop']=false` will actually do make it be recognized as falsy. I am not sure how robust this fact is when considered cross-browserly. Is there any difference among browsers?

Comment: I prefer the word [falsy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Boolean)

Comment: According to this, having the value present is considered true and you'd be safer going that way rather than setting false. - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boolean attributes are explained here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2

> Some attributes play the role of boolean variables (e.g., the selected
>   attribute for the OPTION element). Their appearance in the start tag
>   of an element implies that the value of the attribute is "true". Their
>   absence implies a value of "false".
>
> Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the
>   attribute itself (e.g., selected="selected").

So, while some browsers may interpret the string "false" as if the value was not set, others may not decide to (which is the correct behavior). Actually, as far as I know (or *thought*), any non-empty string usually sets the value to on/true (regardless of what the spec says is a legal value). I believe this is also undefined behavior, so this may change as well or be different from browser to browser (don't rely on it).

The bottom line is, just because a browser or two may deviate from the spec doesn't mean that *you* should. Removing the attribute entirely is the way to go.

**Addendum**: Looking at your comments and question a little closer, I think you may be confused about attribute values in general. In HTML, `attr=false` and `attr="false"` are exactly the same. Quotes are not required in any version of HTML (unless they are needed to remove ambiguity when the value contains spaces). For instance:

```
<input class=required>
<!-- This is fine -->

<input class=title required>
<!-- this is fine too, but "required" will be parsed as an attribute -->

<input class="title required">
<!-- To have two classes, we need the quotes -->
```

All attribute values (on elements that have them) are treated as strings. In other words, there is no such thing as a true boolean *value* (or `NULL` value) in HTML like there is in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum, but I am aware that in html, they are interpreted as strings. That is why I was mentioning javascript. In javascript, I can do things like `['loop']=false` without quotes around `false`, and that is different from `['loop']='false'`. Your answer helped.

Comment: @sawa: Sorry about the addendum then. I've never seen anything like `['loop']=false` in javascript for that, perhaps `element.loop = false`. Not sure where you got that syntax? I also see you're from CT. So am I. Sorry about that as well :)

Comment: I see, you are also in CT. Your answer helped me, and I can't see problem in it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @WesleyMurch what about scenario like this: parent defines `contenteditable`, but the child wants to disable it? If we remove the attribute, it "inherits" the property of being editable from the parent.

Comment: Okay, never mind: `contenteditable` is not a boolean attribute, but rather an enumerated attribute with possible values of `true`, `false` and `''`. Talk about inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

Just so anyone who needs this in the future:

`loop=false` remains `true` unless the entire `loop` attribute is removed. Basically, the presence of just `loop` is what a tag needs to do something else. You need to use something like jQuery to remove the entier `loop` attribute (or at least that's what I would do). Now, if you set a different undefined attribute to `false`, then you are able to recognize it as `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The `audio` element is an HTML5 element, so regarding its meaning, you should consult the HTML5 drafts. In this case, see the [definition of boolean attributes](http://developers.whatwg.org/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute) in the developer version of the WHATWG draft. It says, in effect, a) that the presence or absence of the attribute determines whether the DOM attribute value is `true` or `false`, and b) as a requirement on documents, the value must be empty or (case-insensitively) the attribute name, in this case `loop=''` or `loop="loop"`. The use of quotation marks around the value are defined elsewhere.

Thus, browsers are required to recognize `loop=false` to mean the same as `loop=loop` or `loop=true`, but authors must not use such constructs, and HTML5 checkers issue error messages about them.

(Basically, you’re supposed to use just `loop` in HTML serialization of HTML5 and `loop="loop"` in XHTML serialization.)

Thus, if you have a variable `x` in JavaScript with an `audio` element object as its value, `x.loop` has the value `true` or `false` whereas `x.attributes['loop'].value` indicates the value used in HTML markup (which is usually not interesting as such).

There’s a further complication as regards to Firefox: it still does not seem to support the `loop` attribute (see the question [HTML5 Audio Looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273552/html-5-audio-looping)). This means that if you set e.g. `loop="loop"`, `x.attributes['loop'].value` will be `loop` but Firefox does not even set `x.loop` (i.e., it is `undefined`), still less implement the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer tailored to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing strings and real Boolean types. Javascript has a Boolean datatype with two possible values of true and false (without quotes). Strings can contain any text, so can they contain "true" and "false" with quotes. Setting a property to non-null and non-false yields true, so the following will accour:

```
var a = true; // true
var b = false; // false
var c = "true"; // true
var d = "false" // true
var e = null; // false;
var f = 0; // false
var g = 1; // true
```

Note the similarities with C.

Comment: He's actually referring to the HTML part of it and not JS. The question isn't tagged properly

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Misunderstood the question

Comment: Hey, it's not the case that I was not reading carefully enough... it's the case that it's tagged "javascript"!

Comment: I am doing it through javascript, and am distinguishing `false` and `"false"`.