# Jquery Attribute selector click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'am trying to select a `div` with a specific attribute. I want the `div` to be clicked only if there is a specific `attribute` with a `true` value.The problem is that if i click the `div` again the alert still shows up whereas it has the `attribute` with `false` value.

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-spinner="true">Click Here</a>
```

Jquery

```
$("a[data-spinner='true']").click(function() {
        $("a[data-spinner='true']").attr("data-spinner",false);
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: Either remove the event handler after the first click, or use event delegation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that you attach the event when the element has the attribute. The fact you change the attribute afterwards does not remove that event handler, so it is always called.

There are several ways to fix this.

The first is to use a delegated event handler, which will always account for the current attribute value:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-spinner="true"]', function() {
    $(this).attr("data-spinner", false);
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Another method is to check the state of the attribute within the click handler itself:

```
$("a[data-spinner]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('spinner')) {
        $(this).data('spinner', false)
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

Note that this method allows you to use the `data()` method which is considered better practice.

You could also remove the event handler using `off()` on the first click, or just use `one()` to attach the event - depending on the other logic in the page which sets the `data` attributes' value.

Comment: You just beat me :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't redeclare the event when you change the value of `data-spnner`.
You must programatically handle that instead, like so:

```
$("a[data-spinner]").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.data('spinner')){
        alert("clicked");
    }

    $this.data('spinner',false);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add to Rory McCrossan's answer that, accordingly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775782/setting-false-value-vs-removing-an-attribute), you also should unset the attribute using [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```
$("a[data-spinner='true']").removeAttr("data-spinner");
```